# ALTER TABLE (to add a new column) does not work

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, alter

Instructions: add column to Nonappliance named ON_HAND_VALUE with a 7-digit, two decimal place and set all values to ON_HAND_VALUE is ON_HAND * PRICE.

The last two lines/commands are what's giving me the error "column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition". I don't know what I am doing wrong. Someone help me please :(

```
CREATE TABLE NONAPPLIANCE
(
    PART_NUM CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION CHAR(15),
    ON_HAND DECIMAL(4,0),
    CLASS CHAR(2),
    PRICE DECIMAL(6,2) 
);

INSERT INTO NONAPPLIANCE 
    SELECT 
        PART_NUM, DESCRIPTION, ON_HAND, CLASS, PRICE 
    FROM 
        Part 
    WHERE 
        CLASS != 'AP';

UPDATE NONAPPLIANCE 
SET DESCRIPTION = 'Steam Iron' 
WHERE PART_NUM = 'AT94';

UPDATE NONAPPLIANCE 
SET PRICE = PRICE * 1.03 
WHERE CLASS = 'SG';

INSERT INTO NONAPPLIANCE 
VALUES ('TL92', 'Edge Trimmer', '11', 'HW', 29.95);

DELETE FROM NONAPPLIANCE 
WHERE CLASS = 'SG';

UPDATE NONAPPLIANCE 
SET CLASS = NULL 
WHERE PART_NUM = 'FD21';

ALTER TABLE NONAPPLIANCE 
    ADD ON_HAND_VALUE DECIMAL(7,2);

UPDATE NONAPPLIANCE 
SET ON_HAND_VALUE = PRICE * ON_HAND;
```

Comment: what happens when you do a `select on_hand_value from nonappliance` after your `alter table ..` statement?

Comment: It repeats this, "column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition". When I do SELECT * after ALTER TABLE, it will show the column with "NULL"  for every row.

Comment: so the column hasn't been added to the table. try the `update` part of the query in a different session

Comment: are you saying do it after everything else?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is Oracle-Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I think you need to define the column as `DECIMAL(9, 2)`. This will give you seven digits to the left of the decimal point and 2 digits to the right. Best of luck.